# no-input Turing Machine which accepts in k or fewer steps

Tags: turing-machines, computability

Can we prove by induction that $A_k$ is computable for every choice of $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

$A_k$ is the set of descriptions of a no-input Turing Machine which accepts in $k$ or fewer steps.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69833222/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/145400/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

Well, just simulate $M$ for $k$ steps and see if it accepts or not

---

Or, if you want to prove by induction for some reason (there shouldn't be any reason to do this), then just run the machine for one step and then use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to specify. How to prove it by induction proof?